# Update a tableView his widthContraint after rotating the device

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, constraints, tableview

I have a tableView with textFields in it and on portrait I want the widthContstraint 550 and in landscape 1050. I was able to detect the rotation and change the value, but the tableView does not update when rotating, although the amount is changing correctly every time I rotate. So I guess I need to update the new value somewhere?

This is my code:

```
var widthConstraint: CGFloat? = nil

// Override view did load function
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupContent()
        // Rotation detection
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(rotated), name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
         NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    @objc func rotated() {
        // Change the width when rotating
        widthConstraint = DeviceHelper.isIpadAndLandscape() ? 1050 : 550
        // Update the view again after rotating
        tableView?.updateConstraints()
    }

    // Private func setup content
    private func setupContent() {
        self.setupTableView()
    }

    // Private setup table view
    private func setupTableView() {
        self.tableView?.dataSource = self
        self.tableView?.delegate = self
        if let tableView = self.tableView {
            self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        }
        self.tableView?.anchor(top: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: nil, bottom: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, trailing: nil, padding:  UIEdgeInsets(top: 16, left: 0, bottom: 8, right: 0))
        self.leadingAnchorConstraint = self.tableView?.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor)
        self.trailingAnchorConstraint = self.tableView?.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor)
        self.widthAnchorConstraint = self.tableView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: widthConstraint ?? 550)
        self.centerXAnchorConstraint = self.tableView?.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor)
        self.setupConstraints()
        
    }
```

Comment: remove all constraints and call func again i guess

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I changed now the fixed values to UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, which is better, but it gives me the results reversed when I rotate, any idea to fix this?

Comment: Removing all constraints and setting them up again is very slow, don't do that. Instead, you just need to update the `constant` property of the existing constraint.